# Mockito nested calling

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have the following classes:

```java
class LibraryClass implements LibraryInterface {
    @Override
    public void calculate(Order order)
    {
        //some logic
    }
    @Override
    protected void findAll(Order order)
    {
     //some logic
    }

    protected Map resetAllValues(Order order)
    {
     //some logic
    }
    @Override
    protected void sum(order) {//somelogic}
}
```

```java
class MyCustomClass extends LibraryClass {
    @Override
    public void calculate(Order order)
    {
        findAll(order);

    }

    @Override
    protected void findAll(Order order)
        {
            //some logic
        final Map taxValueMap = resetAllValues(order);

        sum(order);
        }

    @Override
    protected void sum(order)
    {
        int totalCount = getTotalPrice(order);
        int totalItems = getTotalItems(order);
    }
    private int getTotalPrice(Order order) { ...}
    private int getTotalItems(Order order) { ...}
}
```

Where `LibaryClass` and `LibraryInterface` are from a library that I cannot change and I have implemented `MyCustomClass`. My goal is with Mockito to verify that the values of `totalCount` and `totalItems` are some expected value when I pass in calculate method some order.

Now I got stumbled across 2 problems:

1. `resetAllValues(order)` - I want to make this method return an empty map with Mockito, but I can't because the method is protected. If I don't make this method return an empty map for example it tries to make DB calls and throws exceptions.
2. If I manage somehow to do 1., then how should I verify that the returned values from the private methods `getTotalPrice` and `getTotalItems` return the correct value.

Comment: "If I don't make this method return an empty map for example it tries to make DB calls and throws exceptions.". Where is this done?

Comment: this is done in the resetAllValues(order) implemenentation in LibraryClass.

Comment: @xerx593 This resolved my first question, but the 2-nd remains

Comment: 2.: Normally "no one tests 'non-bulic' methods", because: they were all (ideally in all (corner) cases) covered by some "public (method) test"! ;) So you would not "verify on private", but run multiple "pulbic" (calculate()?) tests, which "discover all branches of private methods"...you would verify on the (expectation/consitency) of the main result (..with varying inputs/mocks)

Comment: 2: [How do you unit test private methods?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/100959/41957) -> "You generally don't ..." ;)

Answer (score -1):

The creator of the library may have a reason to limit the visibility of `resetAllValues()` but in your case it prohibits you from applying the *Composition over Inheritance* pattern.

So what I would do is to create a minimal subclass of `LibraryClass` doing nothing but making  `resetAllValues()` public accessible (or at least accessible in the package of `MyCustomClass`). This class is "too simple to fail" so that it does not need unit-tests

```
class MyLibraryClass extends LibraryClass {
   @override Map resetAllValues(Order order){
      return super.resetAllValues(order);
   }
}
```

Then I'd inject an instance of this new class into `MyCustomClass`:

```
class MyCustomClass implements LibraryInterface {
    private final MyLibraryClass delegate;
    MyCustomClass(MyLibraryClass delegate){
       this.delegate=delegate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void calculate(Order order)
    {
        findAll(order);
    }

    @Override
    protected void findAll(Order order)
    {
        //some logic
         final Map taxValueMap = elegate.resetAllValues(order);
         sum(order);
    }

    @Override
    protected void sum(order)
    {
        int totalCount = getTotalPrice(order);
        int totalItems = getTotalItems(order);
    }
    private int getTotalPrice(Order order) { ...}
    private int getTotalItems(Order order) { ...}
}
```

Now Mockito can mock `MyLibraryClass.resetAllValues()`.